# Matching height of empty divs in a table whether contentEditable or not

Tags: html, css

I have a table data editing thing.

1. Some cells are editable, some are not editable
2. Some cells may be empty despite editable or not
3. I'm using contenteditable divs instead of inputs due to the easy auto width expansion quality that they have

Problem lies here:

```css
div {
 border:1px solid black;
 margin:4px;
 padding:4px;
 min-width:40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div contentEditable=true>Editable</div></td>
    <td><div>Not editable</div></td>
    <td><div contentEditable=true></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, all the divs are the same height, except for the read-only empty one. All the other ones derive their height from the font being used and I'd like the same for the last one.

I know I could just define a height for all the divs but I'd like to keep the amount of CSS to a minimum for easier implementation into other projects.

Is there a way to make a div derive its height from the font size despite being empty?

Comment: Could you add a `&nbsp;` to the empty div?

Comment: @MichaelCoker no, it would have complicated the js too much (due to various data entry restriction types) but it gave me an idea, I ended up adding a :after pseudo element to it and set content:"\00a0"

Comment: nice, good idea

Comment: had the same problem. great solution from @user81993. It helped me fixing it.